# Dynamically import file for side effect in production only

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy Chromium to a Lambda with Serverless.

I'm using the `chrome-aws-lambda` library, which expects the compressed executables to be at:

`node_modules/chrome-aws-lambda/bin`

So inside my Webpack configuration, I test for `.br` files and keep their relative path.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
          test: /\.br$/,
          use: [{ loader: 'file-loader', options: { name: '[path][name].[ext]' } }],
        },
    ],
},
```

Inside my PDF service at the top, I import the executables for the side-effect of them being picked up by Webpack

```js
import 'chrome-aws-lambda/bin/aws.tar.br';
import 'chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium.br';
import 'chrome-aws-lambda/bin/swiftshader.tar.br';
```

When deploying to the Lambda, this works correctly.  The issue is locally, Webpack fails to load the compressed files:

```
[
  'C:\\Users\\dev_machine\\client\\project\\node_modules\\chrome-aws-lambda\\bin\\aws.tar.br:1',
  '��MA�A|���]!iC��B�kf\u001c��T@જ�h�\u0001E��r�&�:⛻�\u0014���~�F��G����\u0013����/�\u0014c;\u0016!.\u000eTP %i�u�f��~5�\b`ߝ~%<������He��\t\u0013S�D#�f���FQė�������������������������⌂���m�⌂�s���9�ީ\f��\u0014fh"��\u0014�b��',
  '',
  '',
  'SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token',
  'at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)',
  'at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)',
  'at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)',
  'at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)',
  'at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)',
  'at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)',
  'at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)',
  'at Object.chrome-aws-lambda/bin/aws.tar.br (C:\\Users\\dev_machine\\client\\project\\.webpack\\service\\webpack:\\external "chrome-aws-lambda\\bin\\aws.tar.br":1:1)',
  'at __webpack_require__ (C:\\Users\\dev_machine\\client\\project\\.webpack\\service\\webpack:\\webpack\\bootstrap:19:1)'   
]
```

The compressed files are not used locally.

So it would make sense to only import them if the when the `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'local'`.

I've set `"module": "esnext"` in my `tsconfig.json` and converted the `import 'module'` syntax to `import('module')` syntax, but it complains:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'local') {
    import('chrome-aws-lambda/bin/aws.tar.br');
    import('chrome-aws-lambda/bin/chromium.br');
    import('chrome-aws-lambda/bin/swiftshader.tar.br');
}
```

```
Cannot find module 'chrome-aws-lambda/bin/aws.tar.br' or its corresponding type declarations
```

likely because it's not a js/typescript file.

How do I either load the file correctly locally or import it only outside of local development?

Comment: If you think you've found a solution, then you should **not** edit it into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There was development only configuration that was preventing the first approach from working.

Removing this line fixed it:

`module.exports.externals = [require('webpack-node-externals')()];`